# Radio button as image to cover a bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I found this solution to create radio buttons as images:
https://gist.github.com/rcotrina94/7828886

I want to have one radio button image to cover a whole column, so I can have four radio buttons that cover an entire row, like this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2RBv.png)

I have tried changing the width without any success, here is my code: https://www.bootply.com/SNl7acRBWW

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 image-selector">
        <input checked="checked" id="one" name="image" value="one" type="radio">
        <label class="select one" for="one"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 image-selector">
        <input id="two" name="image" value="two" type="radio">
        <label class="select two" for="two"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 image-selector">
        <input id="three" name="image" value="three" type="radio">
        <label class="select three" for="three"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 image-selector">
        <input id="four" name="image" value="four" type="radio">
        <label class="select four" for="four"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need to set the `width` of `.select` to `100%` (so that the `label` can occupy the full-width of the container), and the `background-size` to `cover` (so that the image can stretch the available space of the column), e.g: https://www.bootply.com/uMcRBdzBnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make them position absolute and stretch them using top/left/right/bottom property :

*I changed md to xs here so we can see it on the snippet, no need to change them in your code*

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.image-selector input{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
       -moz-appearance:none;
            appearance:none;
}



.one{background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/200/100/animals);}
.two{background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/200/100/people);}
.three{background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/200/100/tech);}
.four{background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/200/100/nature);}

.image-selector-2 input:active +.select, .image-selector input:active +.select{opacity: .9;}
.image-selector-2 input:checked +.select, .image-selector input:checked +.select{
    -webkit-filter: none;
       -moz-filter: none;
            filter: none;
}
.image-selector {
    position:relative;
    min-height:200px!important;
}
.select{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
            filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}
.select:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
            filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-3 image-selector">
       <input checked="checked" id="one" type="radio" name="image" value="one">
        <label class="select one" for="one"></label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3 image-selector">
       <input id="two" type="radio" name="image" value="two">
        <label class="select two" for="two"></label>
  </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3 image-selector">
       <input id="three" type="radio" name="image" value="three">
        <label class="select three" for="three"></label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3 image-selector">
       <input id="four" type="radio" name="image" value="four">
        <label class="select four" for="four"></label>
   </div>
</div>
```